# Why low swappiness (10) leads to system crashes?

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage, numpy

As I have 128 GB of RAM, I wanted to minimize swap usage by setting `vm.swappiness` to 10.

I ran a bath (`snakemake -j 1`) of memory-heavy operations in Python: subtracting two arrays up to 15 GB each, then calculating norms of the difference.  Surprisingly my system started to misbehave: Thunderbird crashed, then so did my graphic environment (XFCE with lightdm) effectively killing my screen session with the bath running.  Now I wonder: why?

Moreover, my scripts tends to fail with segmentation faults when processing the biggest arrays.  Also, after graphic environment respawned it swapped my monitors (pun intended) and did not allow me to re-swap them with Display settings.  `service lightdm restart` after `sysctl vm.swappiness=60` was necessary.

I had plenty (932 GB) of swap available, so it is not that my system suddenly ran out of memory.  RAM chips also seems to work (17 passes of Memtest86+ revealed no error).

**I ask about the reason behind crashes** of other programs (Thunderbird, screen session, graphic environment).  Even if my programs were poorly written, I would expect their impact to be limited extensive swapping.  A total XFCE session restart is something that definitively should not happen.  And by restart I mean restart, not freezing or slowdown due to swapping.

Comment: Try completely turning the swap off (comment out the swap entry in `/etc/fstab`). It is really not necessary with 128 GB of RAM.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am not looking for walkaround. I am looking for understanding what happened.

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed the memory is good? I’ve had faulty sticks (both ECC and non-ECC) contribute to behaviours like this in the past.

Comment: I don't know what happened. But from my experience (I use Ubuntu on desktops and workstations with large RAM), beyond 8 GB memory or so, swap does not help in most cases, but rather slows the computer down.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It helps when I am working with arrays closer to 120 GB.

Comment: Try adjusting/increasing [min_free_kbytes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583848/why-do-programs-including-xorg-close-when-out-of-ram-but-swap-is-near-empty/585599#585599)

Comment: Related: [How to auto move swap back to RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1347219/968501)

Comment: @matigo I have ran 17 passes of Memtest86+ - memory seems to be good.

Comment: @karel No. Why do you think it explain crashes I mentioned?

Comment: @karel I ask about the reason behind crashes specifically.  I want to understand why other programs crash when I expect them to be just slowed down by (possibly suboptimal) swapping.

Comment: @karel What is the connection between number of inotify-monitored files and system crashes when running memory-heavy processes?  Just in case I have tried `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288` and `fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192` - after 12 successful jobs snakemake crashed (Segmentation fault).  So did my graphic session, screen session luckily survived.  Interestingly, a `bash` process has gone wild and now it uses 100% CPU time.

Comment: @matigo You were pretty close.  It was swap partition what was bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: **It does not seem to.**

[The problem was with badblocks at swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1487450/633655) which may or might not be related to the reduced swappiness.  Someone more experienced may tell, whether swappiness affect disk wear.

I have succesfully ran my bath with `vm.swappiness=0`.  4h ago I started another bath with `vm.swappiness=10` - so far everything is working fine.  If system starts to misbehave (and no badblocks are found) I will update the answer.