# How can I check whether Memtest86+ has frozen or is irresponsive due to running a test?

Tags: boot, grub2, ram, memtest

Due to the comment on my question [Why low swappiness (10) leads to system crashes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486228/why-low-swappiness-10-leads-to-system-crashes#comment2602708_1486228) I decided to run memory test.

When It starts automatically with the default "Fail-Safe" option, the screen seemed to be frozen (only red "+" was blinking) at Time: 0:00:01:

[image]

There is no response to neither (ESC) nor (c) and I may only guess what SP or CR stand for.

When I run "Multi-Threading (SMP)" option, screen changes for the first 27 seconds, and (c) responds with a list of options.  Then the screen seems to be frozen again:

[image]

Is it some misbehavior, or does the test requires screen to be frozen?

Comment: Firstly, memtest86 does not run within Ubuntu, so I'm not sure this is a Ubuntu specific question (*as Ubuntu isn't running when memtest86 is!*).  I have noted on some boxes the program does lock up, yet if I take the RAM out of that box, and perform the same memory test (using same *live* Ubuntu ISO) on another box; I can get it to complete successfully; thus I don't see the issue as bad ram, just that the app has issues with some hardware/firmware combinations. I have no explanation sorry; just what I've experienced.

Comment: I suggest that you try a newer version of the FOSS memtest86+ or the free memtest (free to download and use, but the source code is not open). See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi/917998#917998) and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258991/where-is-the-memtest-option-on-the-ubuntu-64-bit-live-cd/952326#952326).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it looks like it is frozen, it is frozen.**

It is [a known bug of Memtest86+ 5.01 coming with Ubuntu 20.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1876157).

In my case the solution was to use ISO with Memtest86+ 6.20 downloaded from https://memtest.org.